# Serially loop over asyncronous operations in RxJava

Tags: rx-java

I have to call this method

```
Observable<Boolean> doOperation(int i);
```

multiple times.  The catch is, I have to wait for the previous Observable to complete before I move on.  I know I could do this:

```
Observable.just(null)
    .flatMap(v -> doOperation(1))
    .flatMap(v -> doOperation(2))
    .flatMap(v -> doOperation(3))
```

However, I was really hoping to do something like this:

```
Observable.range(1, 10)
    .flatMap(i -> doOperation(i))
```

However, in this latter construct, the range operator runs at full steam and sends all 10 operations immediately.  The nature of the operations requires that I wait until doOperation(1) has completed before I fire doOperation(2), etc.

I wonder if there's some way to make this happen in Rx beside the first example above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it!  Instead of flatMap(), you can use concatMap().  ConcatMap will wait until Observable n completes before it subscribes to Observable n+1.

You can see this by creating a method

```
private static Observable<Integer> doOperation(int i)
{
    logger.info("Calling method with [{}]", i);
    return Observable.just(i).delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
}
```

and then subscribing to the stream.

```
Observable.range(1, 10)
    .concatMap(i -> doOperation(i))
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved easily using `PublishSubject`. Inside the `doSomeOperation(integer)` method you've to call `limit.onNext(YOUR_NEXT_INTEGER)` to make the next call when the current one finishes. As you can see, The `doSomeOperation(integer)` calls the next operation only when the current one finishes so there will be no interleaving between operations.

```
PublishSubject<Integer> limit = PublishSubject.create();

        limit.concatMap(doSomeOperation(integer))
                .subscribe();
        limit.onNext(1);
```

this is recursive until your limit. Hope this helps you